# Xcode 9.1 won't clean project if custom build location

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9.1

I'm using Xcode 9.1 on an iOS project and the 'Product' -> 'Clean Build Folder' is grayed out if I set a custom build location (in 'Preferences' -> 'Locations' -> 'Advanced').

If I set the build location to "Unique", I can clean without issue, but as soon as I change it to "Custom", the 'Clean Build Folder' option is grayed.

I tried restarting Xcode, the computer, cleaning Derived Data, cleaning the Build folder manually, but nothing seems to work.

I don't have the problem if I open the same project on Xcode 8.3.

Anyone had this issue before?